# Output from R package to user's home filespace without being "malicious or anti-social"

Tags: r, cran

I'm writing a package to generate a PDF of bridge card hands.  While intermediate files are saved to temporary files and then unlinked, the ultimate PDF needs to be saved so that it can be printed or saved into a collection.  This contradicts the CRAN Repository Policy:

> Packages should not write in the user’s home filespace (including
> clipboards), nor anywhere else on the file system apart from the R
> session’s temporary directory (or during installation in the location
> pointed to by TMPDIR: and such usage should be cleaned up). Installing
> into the system’s R installation (e.g., scripts to its bin directory)
> is not allowed.

How can the code be both compliant and the PDF available to the user?

Thank you,

TC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function could just accept a filename (so the user can put it in his home if he wants to), and if none given (missing), you could generate a temp pdf file and verbosely say you put it there?

Comment: Thank you.  This seems a pragmatic solution, let's see if it passes the CRAN tests.